# No catalog entry found for partition ID xxxxx

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, corruption

I need help understanding this error message in order explain the issue to management. Meeting is Monday afternoon. The problem occurred a few days ago and was resolved via restore, so the problem is not ongoing.

The error message:

No catalog entry found for partition ID 72057599467978752 in database 8. The metadata is inconsistent. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a metadata corruption.

Here's what I know so far:

1. There were a number of user tables produced this similar errors when I ran a select count(*) against them.|
2. In the corrupt db's sys.partitions there was no partition_id with the number 72057599467978752.
3. In the restored db's sys.partitions the number 72057599467978752
   does exist.

Here's what I need to know:

1. What does the partition_id refer to? Is is a location in a physical
   file?
2. What could have happened to cause the partition to disappear.
3. Where else in the database is this partition_id(72057599467978752)
       stored, it must be somewhere in order to put it in the error
       message.

Thanks for your help.

Brian

NB: The DBCC CHECKDB didn't work for us. 
Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a **system table is inconsistent.** Check previous errors.

Comment: Figured out that several sys.tables.object_id's, for user tables, are not found it the sys.partitions table. My only question is really what could of happened to those rows in the sys.partitions table.

Answer (score 2):

1. All tables, even if not partitioned, are tracked internally as partitions. A non-partitioned table is a single partition. Partition ID is the ID value for that partition. It does not relate to any specific location.
2. The record for that partition is missing. Somehow it was deleted or the page or section of page it was written to was over-written.
3. Then the corruption occurred prior to that backup. Do you have any older backups?

Comment: Hi Robert. We will be opening a ticket with MS. Thanks for the answers.The corruption occurred after the last backup. After the restore the partitions where found in sys.partitions.

Comment: It's in the page header. It's in the page header of the pages pointing to it (if it's a data page), IAM pages.

Comment: MS said the client has a hardware issue. So that's the good/bad news. btw I can't mark your answer until my reputation get to 15..lol.